# I plagiarized in my Bachelor's thesis, and after a year,went back and redid it unofficially. Should I push for some official action?

Tags: graduate-admissions, plagiarism

My supervisor does not want to push this further and take official action since this was a lone incident and I had health issues at that point. However, since I am not getting closure, I do not feel like I have a go-ahead to re-apply to universities. I feel that future advisers/people I write to for grad school should be aware of this but do not know how to bring it up, since there's no official record of this. By plagiarized, I do mean that there's no question/argument about it, there's some straight up copy-paste. I have reworked it now, but feel like I have put an end to further education for myself. I also turned down some grad school admits (this + monetary issues). Any advice/clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: **Please don’t write answers in comments**. It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, as well as having other problems. Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you think further advisors should know about it?

Comment: I wonder what is your REAL question. It seems you have several unresolved issues about academic career, and instead of making a decision of committing yourself fully or choosing another career, you want to put this decision to others and want potential supervisors to reject you based on this incident. If I misjudged you, then you should explain what do you actually want to achieve, why do you want to tell people you are ethically not suitable for this career when you apply to them.

Comment: @Greg Guilt's a hell of a thing. Especially if you've got the impression that only the pure and honorable deserve anything good, and everyone else should be punished.

Comment: @ff524 question if possed in the way that only Yes or No is applicable as answer

Comment: If you had an STD you wouldn't go telling every random person you met ... honestly, they dont want to know.  This isnt to say that you should lie about it if questioned, however, you may want to consider better life choices in the future.

Comment: @Greg I would doubt whether I want to invest years in an academic career as well if I had to live with the possibility that it all comes shattering down because someone reads my bachelor thesis and there has never been an official inquiry about it. I see no need to second-guess OP's intentions in asking this question.

Answer (score 6):

No, don't push, and don't tell it to future advisors etc.

You shouldn't feel this obligation to offer up the truth, especially about bad things, to people who don't even want or need to hear it.

Lying and openly telling all of your problems are totally different (especially when not even asked about them, by people who don't even want to hear about them, who have the power to make decisions that will be harmful to you).

Your supervisor thinks you are a good person, and they don't want to make unnecessary problems for you. You've even shown your character by going back and re-doing it. If your supervisor thought you were lying or that you would keep doing it in the future or that other people would be harmed by you elsewhere, they would want to make official problems for you.

So what I mean about lying/deception vs openly telling everyone all of your problems: there are people who are always only thinking about getting to the next step, and will lie to their classmates/coworkers, or steal from them etc. If some interviewer asks you "did you ever plagiarize anything?" then you can tell them (but if you believe they shouldn't even ask that question, or that the answer is irrelevant, then feel free to lie). But if you apply for a PHD or something and they ask about it, then you should probably tell them, and tell them the whole story.

And I don't mean you have to let them ask exactly the right question. If they ask something that seems like it's related, and that they would want to know this, feel free to tell it. I just mean, if they ask some general question about your history, you shouldn't tell them every bad little thing. Would you tell some random people at the bus stop too? "Hey man do you go here?" "Yeah I go here, but I plagiarized this thing like 2 years ago, I thought you should know". You know what I mean?

Just forget about it. Even the people in charge of dealing with it don't want to keep going with it. Their job is to make official problems for people who are doing it as part of a pattern and who don't want to correct their actions, to prevent future harm to other people.

Answer (score 4):

No. You should not push for further action. The university holds the authority to determine whether or not to take disciplinary action with respect to violations of its own policy. As far as the university is concerned, the matter has already been settled. Personal closure is a separate matter that neither your university nor another university can provide for you. Accept and appreciate your advisor's kind judgement, learn from your mistake, and keep moving forward.
In general, you should not deliberately call attention to this when applying or interviewing for graduate school. It is normal and expected for applicants to 'put their best foot forward'. Disclosure is fine, if asked or if it would contribute something constructive to the interaction. Most of the time,  bringing it up is likely to distract from more important topics, such as what you hope to get out of the program, how you expect to contribute, and so on.